# Get id of element which raised event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dom-events

I am working in asp.net mvc. I have following JS

```
<script>
    function fun()
    {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    }
</script>
```

And following code in View

```
@
{
  int i=1;
}
@for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
  <a href="" id="@i" onclick="fun()">ABC</a>
}
```

I want to get ID of anchor which calls `fun()`, but i get `undefined` value always. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Pass **this**

```
<a href="" id="@i" onclick="fun(this)">ABC</a>

 function fun(elem) {
    alert(elem.id);
  }
```

In the case you are refering to , **this** will refer to the window object . So if you pass the `element to the function` , that elemnent will be available in the scope of the function which acts as a closure.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<script>
  function fun(el) {
    alert($(el).attr("id"));
  }
</script>
```

and:

```
@
{
  int i=1;
}
@for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
  <a href="" id="@i" onclick="fun(this)">ABC</a>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If i absolutely had to do it with an onclick attribute, i would call the function with `this` as the context, and while i'm at it, pass the event object.

```
<a href="" id="@i" onclick="fun.call(this,event)">ABC</a>
```

(no changes needed to `fun` method)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that because you have to send the object itself in the onclick event like this:

```
@for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
  <a href="" id="@i" onclick="fun(this)">ABC</a>
}
```

And then you can access to its properties:

```
<script>
        function fun(obj)
        {
            alert(obj.id);//obj.name, obj.value also you could take.
        }
    </script>
```